# Why my Grub background color become Grey after installing GNOME Desktop?

Tags: grub2

[image]

After I run

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop

my grub background color turn grey.

Do you know why my grub background color become grey instead of purple?

Comment: Because Gnome changes it :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your GRUB background changes color based on what display manager or desktop environment you use. For example, I switched to KDE a few months ago and my GRUB turned black.

Comment: do you know how to change it back?

Comment: Unfortunately, no @Yulianto